# Fill missing timestamps and apply different operations on different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data in below format

```
user   timestamp             flowers     total_flowers

xyz   01-01-2020 00:05:00    15          15
xyz   01-01-2020 00:10:00    5           20
xyz   01-01-2020 00:15:00    21          41
xyz   01-01-2020 00:35:00    1           42

...

xyz   01-01-2020 11:45:00   57           1029
xyz   01-01-2020 11:55:00   18           1047
```

Expected Output:

```
user   timestamp             flowers     total_flowers

xyz   01-01-2020 00:05:00    15          15
xyz   01-01-2020 00:10:00    5           20
xyz   01-01-2020 00:15:00    21          41
xyz   01-01-2020 00:20:00    0           41
xyz   01-01-2020 00:25:00    0           41
xyz   01-01-2020 00:30:00    0           41
xyz   01-01-2020 00:35:00    1           42

...

xyz   01-01-2020 11:45:00   57           1029
xyz   01-01-2020 11:50:00   0            1029
xyz   01-01-2020 11:55:00   18           1047
```

So I want to fill timestamps with 5 mins interval and fill flowers column by 0 and total_flowers column by previous value(ffill)

My efforts:

```
start_day = "01-01-2020"
end_day = "01-01-2020"

start_time = pd.to_datetime(f"{start_day} 00:05:00+05:30")
end_time = pd.to_datetime(f"{end_day} 23:55:00+05:30")
dates = pd.date_range(start=start_time, end=end_time, freq='5Min')

df =  df.set_index('timestamp').reindex(dates).reset_index(drop=False).reindex(columns=df.columns)
```

How do I fill `flowers` column with zeros and `total_flower` column with `ffill` and I am also getting values in `timestamp` column as `Nan`

Actual Output:

```
user   timestamp flowers     total_flowers

xyz   Nan    15          15
xyz   Nan    5           20
xyz   Nan    21          41
xyz   Nan    Nan         Nan
xyz   Nan    Nan         Nan
xyz   Nan    Nan         Nan
xyz   Nan    1           42

...

xyz   Nan   57           1029
xyz   Nan   Nan          Nan
xyz   Nan   18           1047
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reindex and refill

If you construct the `dates` such that you can `reindex` your timestamps, you can then just do some `fillna` and `ffill` operations.  I had to remove the timezone information, but you should be able to add that back if your data are timezone aware.  Here's the full example using some of your data:

```
d = {'user': {0: 'xyz', 1: 'xyz', 2: 'xyz', 3: 'xyz'},
 'timestamp': {0: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:05:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:10:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:15:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:35:00')},
 'flowers': {0: 15, 1: 5, 2: 21, 3: 1},
 'total_flowers': {0: 15, 1: 20, 2: 41, 3: 42}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#  user           timestamp  flowers  total_flowers
#0  xyz 2020-01-01 00:05:00       15             15
#1  xyz 2020-01-01 00:10:00        5             20
#2  xyz 2020-01-01 00:15:00       21             41
#3  xyz 2020-01-01 00:35:00        1             42

#as you did, but with no TZ
start_day = "01-01-2020"
end_day = "01-01-2020"

start_time = pd.to_datetime(f"{start_day} 00:05:00")
end_time = pd.to_datetime(f"{end_day} 00:55:00")
dates = pd.date_range(start=start_time, end=end_time, freq='5Min', name="timestamp")

#filling the nas and reformatting
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df = df.reindex(dates)
df['user'].ffill(inplace=True)
df['flowers'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['total_flowers'].ffill(inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
             timestamp user  flowers  total_flowers
0  2020-01-01 00:05:00  xyz     15.0           15.0
1  2020-01-01 00:10:00  xyz      5.0           20.0
2  2020-01-01 00:15:00  xyz     21.0           41.0
3  2020-01-01 00:20:00  xyz      0.0           41.0
4  2020-01-01 00:25:00  xyz      0.0           41.0
5  2020-01-01 00:30:00  xyz      0.0           41.0
6  2020-01-01 00:35:00  xyz      1.0           42.0
7  2020-01-01 00:40:00  xyz      0.0           42.0
8  2020-01-01 00:45:00  xyz      0.0           42.0
9  2020-01-01 00:50:00  xyz      0.0           42.0
10 2020-01-01 00:55:00  xyz      0.0           42.0
```

### Resample and refill

You can also use `resample` here using `asfreq()`, then do the filling as before.  This is convenient for finding the dates (and should get around the timezone stuff):

```
# resample and then fill the gaps
# same df as constructed above
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df.resample('5T').asfreq()

df['user'].ffill(inplace=True)
df['flowers'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['total_flowers'].ffill(inplace=True)
df.index.name='timestamp'
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Same output:

```
            timestamp  flowers  total_flowers user
0 2020-01-01 00:05:00       15           15.0  xyz
1 2020-01-01 00:10:00        5           20.0  xyz
2 2020-01-01 00:15:00       21           41.0  xyz
3 2020-01-01 00:20:00        0           41.0  xyz
4 2020-01-01 00:25:00        0           41.0  xyz
5 2020-01-01 00:30:00        0           41.0  xyz
6 2020-01-01 00:35:00        1           42.0  xyz
```

I couldn't find a way to do the filling *during* the resampling.  For instance, using

```
df = df.resample('5T').agg({'flowers':'sum',
                            'total_flowers':'ffill',
                            'user':'ffill'})
```

does not work (it gets you to the same place as `asfreq`, but there's more room for accidentally missing out columns here).  Which is odd because when applying `ffill` over the whole DataFrame, the missing data can be forward filled (but we only want that for some columns, and the user column also gets dropped).  But simply using `asfreq` and doing the filling after the fact seems fine to me with few columns.

Answer (score 1):

### crossed with @Tom

You are almost there:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz'],
    'timestamp': ['01-01-2020 00:05:00', '01-01-2020 00:10:00', '01-01-2020 00:15:00', '01-01-2020 00:35:00'],
                   'flowers':[15, 5, 21, 1],
                   'total_flowers':[15, 20, 41, 42]
})
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
r = pd.date_range(start=df['timestamp'].min(), end=df['timestamp'].max(), freq='5Min')
df = df.set_index('timestamp').reindex(r).rename_axis('timestamp').reset_index()
df['user'].ffill(inplace=True)
df['total_flowers'].ffill(inplace=True)
df['flowers'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

leads to the following output:

```
    timestamp           user    flowers total_flowers
0   2020-01-01 00:05:00 xyz     15.0    15.0
1   2020-01-01 00:10:00 xyz      5.0    20.0
2   2020-01-01 00:15:00 xyz     21.0    41.0
3   2020-01-01 00:20:00 xyz      0.0    41.0
4   2020-01-01 00:25:00 xyz      0.0    41.0
5   2020-01-01 00:30:00 xyz      0.0    41.0
6   2020-01-01 00:35:00 xyz      1.0    42.0
```